# Strong Induction on Recursive Sequence

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, induction, recursion

I attempted to prove the following but am unsure if my logic is solid.

Define the sequence of numbers $A_i$, by
$A_0 = 2$

$A_{n+1} = \frac{A_n}{2} + \frac{1}{A_n}$ for $n\geq 1$
Prove that $A_n \leq\sqrt2 + \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n\geq0$.

proof attempt: (using strong induction)

assume $A_n$ is true for $A_0$, $A_1$, ... $A_n$,
prove $A_{n+1} \leq\sqrt2 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$
substitute $A_n$ into recursive definition:
$A_{n+1} = \frac{\sqrt2 + \frac{1}{2^n}}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt2 + \frac{1}{2^n}}$

$\frac{\sqrt2 + \frac{1}{2^n}}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt2 + \frac{1}{2^n}} \leq \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$
This is where I am unsure if my thinking is correct. I attempted to take the limit as n -> infinity such that all the 1/2^n terms go to 0.
We are left with...

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} +\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \leq\sqrt2$
which gives

$\frac{2}{\sqrt2}\leq\sqrt2$,

which is true...but I am not sure if I just proved it for all n or just very large n.

Could somebody offer some feedback?  Thank you.

Comment: This is hard to read.  Do you mean $A_{n+1}=\frac {A_n}2+\frac 1{A_n}$?

Comment: Assuming you do, then Hint:  it's easier to prove $\sqrt 2 ≤ A_n ≤ \sqrt 2 +\frac 1{2^n}$.

Comment: yes lulu thank you

Comment: Did that hint get the job done?  I always like situations where it is easier to prove an apparently stronger statement.

Comment: i am still not sure how to substitute that into the An+1

Comment: Well, I didn't write it all out but let's see:  if we have $\sqrt 2 ≤ A_n≤\sqrt 2 +\frac 1{2^n}$ then we have $\frac 1{A_n}≥ \frac 1{\sqrt 2}=\frac {\sqrt 2}2$ so $A_{n+1}≤ \frac 12\times \left(\sqrt 2 +\frac 1{2^n}\right)+\frac {\sqrt 2}2$ which is what we want.  Now all you have to prove is that $A_{n+1}≥\sqrt 2$.

Comment: To conclude...the last bit is easy as the function $f(x)=\frac x2 + \frac 1x$ has an absolute minimum at $(\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 2)$

Comment: where does the 1/2 in the 3rd equation come from?

Comment: oh wow nevermind i understand now!

Comment: No problem.  If you are so inclined, [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site. It makes it a lot easier to ask questions!

Comment: how did you know that An would be >= the sqrt(2)?

Comment: Whenever i want to think about a recursive sequence the first thing I do is to plot a whole lot of values, just to get a feel.  doing that in your case shows that your $A_n$ decrease to $\sqrt 2$.  Not a proof, of course, but very persuasive.

Comment: very insightful, thank you. I will try out that technique.

Comment: I've trying to prove a similar statement, in which $1 \leq A_n \leq \frac{3}{2} $. I managed to prove it's less than 7/4 ...