# Prove inequalities

Tags: inequality

Define the sequence of numbers $A_i$ by

$$A_0 = 2$$

$$A_{n+1} = \frac{A_n}{2} + \frac{1}{A_n}  \quad \text{for} \  n \geq 1$$

Prove that 
$$
A_n \leq \sqrt{2} + \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^n \quad \forall n \geq 0.
$$
I already tried induction but it didn't help in this case.

The question is : beside induction what is other approach to solve this kind of problem ?

Comment: Could you please refer to Mathjax help and edit your question?

Comment: Hint: You have
$$A_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}=\frac{(A_n-\sqrt{2})^2}{2A_n}$$

Comment: @Kelenner what does this equation mean ? It means Ai alway greater than √2  and this will help me with induction or there is another approach ?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2186571/42969 – found instantly using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24A_%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7BA_n%7D%7B2%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7BA_n%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite $$A_{n+1} = \frac{A_n}{2} + \frac{1}{A_n} $$ as
$$A_{n+1} =A_n-\frac{A_n}{2} + \frac{1}{A_n}=A_n-\frac{A_n^2-2}{2A_n}  $$ you probably recognize Newton iterative scheme for solving $A^2-2=0$ starting with a guess $A_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the definition is recursive, induction is natural for this problem, and it works if you first show $A_n \ge \sqrt{2}$, for all $n$.

Based on that strategy, here's a proof . . .

If $A_n\;$is positive, so is $A_{n+1},\;$hence, since $A_0 = 2 > 0,\;$it follows that $A_n > 0,\;$for all $n$.

Note that $A_0 = 2 > \sqrt{2}$.

By AM-GM,
$$A_{n+1} = \frac{A_n}{2} + \frac{1}{A_n} \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}  = \sqrt{2}$$
Thus, $A_n \ge \sqrt{2},\;$for all $n$.

The goal is to prove $A_n \le \sqrt{2} + {\Large{\frac{1}{2^n}}},\;$for all $n$.

Proceed by induction on $n$.

For $n=0,\;$we have $A_0 = 2 < \sqrt{2} + 1 = \sqrt{2} + {\Large{\frac{1}{2^0}}}$.

Assume the inequality $A_n \le \sqrt{2} + {\Large{\frac{1}{2^n}}}\;$holds for some integer $n \ge 0$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;A_{n+1} 
&= \frac{A_n}{2} + \frac{1}{A_n}\\[4pt]
&\le 
\frac
{\sqrt{2} + {\Large{\frac{1}{2^n}}}}{2} +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\[4pt]
&=\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the induction, and thus completes the proof.